# Add custom localized text in DateTimeFormatter, for a new custom TemporalField

Tags: localization, java-8, datetime-format, java-time

I've created a `CENTURY` field that implements `java.time.temporal.TemporalField` - *this question is not focusing on the correct implementation details of such field (which will be handled later), I'm interested in the `DateTimeFormatter` issue as explained below*.

Basically, the field gets the `ChronoField.YEAR` of a temporal object and uses this value to calculate the century (the calculation is made in `getFrom(TemporalAccessor temporal)` method, considering that the 1<sup>st</sup> century is from year 1 to 100 - but as I said, let's not stick too much in these details).

The most basic usage is:

```
LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1).get(CENTURY); // 21
```

Which returns `21` in this case.

The field can also be used in a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy ")
    .appendValue(CENTURY)
    .toFormatter();

System.out.println(fmt.format(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1))); // 01/01/2017 21
```

The output for the above is:

> 01/01/2017 21

---

But what I want to do is to use a custom localized text for this field. If I create a formatter like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy ")
    // century text
    .appendText(CENTURY, TextStyle.SHORT)
    // use English locale
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println(fmt.format(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1))); // 01/01/2017 21
```

Since there's no localized data for my new `CENTURY` field, the text is only its own value `21`.

I'm trying to find a way to add custom localized strings for this field, like it's done with month and day of week, for example (let's assume that I already have the resource bundle properties files set).

Checking the source code, I've found that the formatter internally uses a `TextPrinterParser`, which in turn uses a `DateTimeTextProvider` to get the localized strings, but none of those classes are public and can't be used nor extended. And the API doesn't seem to provide a way to add custom localized strings for new fields.

I could do it only by using reflection and a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` to overwrite the behaviour of the `TextPrinterParser`, but I wonder if there's a better way (that doesn't require all this "magic").

How can this be done (if possible)?

---

I know I could also use [`appendText(TemporalField field, Map<Long,String> textLookup)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendText-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-java.util.Map-), but that wouldn't be a "locale sensitive" solution (although it seems to be the best workaround available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in `java.time.*` today. The `DateTimeTextProvider` class was intended to be extensible, but this got descoped during development. Providing pluggable text providers would be a useful enhancement to Java.